# Excel VBA highlighting macro

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I have this Excel macro I created to highlight all instances of a number if at least one instance is already highlighted before running the macro.

```
Sub highlightXIDs()
    Dim prods As Object: Set prods = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim tRange As Range

    For Each tRange In ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
        If tRange.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then prods.Add Key:=tRange.Value, Item:=tRange.Interior.Color
    Next

    Dim prod As Variant, xidMap As Object
    Set xidMap = getXidMap(ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & lastRow))
    For Each prod In prods.keys
        xidMap(prod).EntireRow.Columns("A").Interior.Color = prods.Item(prod)
    Next prod
End Sub

'get a "map" of each unique xid value to the rows containing it
Function getXidMap(rng As Range) As Object
    Dim rv As Object, c As Range, currVal, cStart, i, tmp
    Set rv = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        tmp = c.Value
        If Len(tmp) > 0 Then
            If rv.exists(tmp) Then
                Set rv(tmp) = Application.Union(c, rv(tmp))
            Else
                rv.Add tmp, c
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    Set getXidMap = rv
End Function
```

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

1. Is this an efficient use of the included vba objects or should I change something?
2. For the line where I check the cell color, which would be more accurate/efficient in finding any cell that has fill color (excluding conditional formatting):

   ```
   .Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone
   ```

   Or

   ```
   .Interior.Color <> -4142
   ```

   Or would these both work the same with the same amount of accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to talk about *variable naming*. I can't read your code and understand what's happening which indicates that your code isn't self-explanatory. One step in accomplishing that is to give variables *meaningful names*:

`lastRow` is good! Otherwise..

`prods` - what is this? a dictionary of product keys? why not `productList` or something similar?

`prod` how is this different than `prods`?  Should it be `productListKey`?

`tRange`, `rv`, `c`, `i` and `tmp` - I have no idea what they should be doing - except for `i` because it's pretty standard.

`cStart`, `currVal` and `i` - you never use them. But if you did  - why not just use the entire word for the description? `currentValue` and `cellStart`

Speaking of `currVal`, `cStart`, `i` and `tmp` - When you don't define your variable, VBA will declare it as a *Variant*, which are [objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcxd6b8.aspx):

> **Performance**. A variable you declare with the Object type is flexible
>   enough to contain a reference to any object. However, when you invoke
>   a method or property on such a variable, you always incur late binding
>   (at run time). To force early binding (at compile time) and better
>   performance, declare the variable with a specific class name, or cast
>   it to the specific data type.

By not declaring variables, you could possibly be paying a penalty.

What is `rv` anyway?

Also you are using `(rng as Range)` in your function - but you're passing it `ByRef` by default. I don't see any need to do that, so `ByVal testRange as Range` would be better.

---

#### Logic

As far as I can tell you make a dictionary of all values with an interior color. Then you make a dictionary of all values `*in the same range as the first dictionary*. Then you compare the dictionaries. Since you're already looping through the range for the second dictionary, I'm not sure what kind of speed gains you're getting considering you could just loop through once.

As for finding unfilled cells - I think they are the same. The `color` is more accurate than `colorindex`. I'd still use the `color` property though as all the rest of my code would use `color` before `colorindex`.

Comment: The function shown is used earlier in my code and that is used as a reference for more efficient manipulation (pertaining strictly to a product-to-product basis). It was created by someone on SO for me and I left the variables as they had them. I know that's no excuse, I should've renamed them and cleaned up a bit, so I fully accept that blame. Also, as far as commenting my code, I'm usually quite strict about that, but as I said in my post I whipped this up in a few minutes in my downtime at work at the time. You are right, I should've name my variables more clearly.

Comment: `prods` is in fact a dictionary of product keys that contain a colorfill. I store the cell value and the color of the cell to fill it after the fact. I probably should've combined those two loops somehow, but how would you suggest I do so? `prod` was meant to be one item in the `prods` dictionary, so I can reference each element in the dictionary as I loop. The function variable `(rng as Range)` is passed by `ByRef` because there are times rows are added/deleted, so it'll keep the actually cell location as my code executes. But, again, I should've explained that a bit better, my apologies.

Comment: Lastly, I figured `color` is more than `colorindex` and I only use `color` throughout my code, so I guess that answers that question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Raystafarian for pointing out some repetition and poor coding practice I've revised my code to look like this

```
Sub highlightXIDs()
    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim currentCell As Range, xidMap As Object

    'Get map of products(xids)
    Set xidMap = getXidMap(ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & lastRow))
    For Each currentCell In ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
        'Check if cell has color
        If currentCell.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
            'If so, set all instances of the xid to that color
            xidMap(currentCell.Value).EntireRow.Columns("A").Interior.Color = currentCell.Interior.Color
        End If
    Next
End Sub

'get a "map" of each unique xid value to the rows containing it
Function getXidMap(rng As Range) As Object
    Dim xidDic As Object: Set xidDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If Len(cell.Value) > 0 Then
            If xidDic.exists(cell.Value) Then
                Set xidDic(cell.Value) = Application.Union(cell, xidDic(cell.Value))
            Else
                xidDic.Add cell.Value, cell
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    Set getXidMap = xidDic
End Function
```

Comment: If you want your revised code reviewed, you should post it as a [follow up question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Kaz I'm not looking for follow-up, I was simply posting adjusted code to show what came to fruition thanks to the help of the other users.

Comment: Out of interest, why not? Learning is an iterative process after all.

Comment: Under normal circumstances I would, but at the moment I have far too much workload (and other pieces of my code) I need to focus on building as our company's import system is changing by the end of April.